# Remove email attachments after saving them and adding save location to email in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I've created this macro that lets me do the following:

1. Select a folder to save attachments to
2. Select a date range to download the email attachments from

After the emails are saved, I need to remove the saved attachment from the email and replace it with a link to the location where it was saved.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SaveMailAttachments()
On Error Resume Next
Dim ns As NameSpace
Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim subFolder As MAPIFolder
Dim Item As Object
Dim Attach As Attachment
Dim FileName As String, fName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Searchdate As String
Dim SentDate As String
Dim sntDate As Date

Searchdate = InputBox("Please enter a Previous date to search from")

saveFolder = BrowseForFolder("Select the folder you will like to save the attachments to.")
If saveFolder = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

  i = 0

   If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no messages in the inbox.", vbInformation, _
                "nothing Found"
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error Resume Next

For Each Item In Inbox.Items
    sntDate = Item.SentOn

    SentDate = Format(sntDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")

    For Each Attach In Item.Attachments
        If Searchdate < SentDate Then
        FileName = saveFolder & "\" & Attach.FileName
        Attach.SaveAsFile FileName
        i = i + 1
        End If

    Next Attach
    'End If

Next Item

End Sub
```

Comment: One reason Dmitry Streblechenko is having trouble helping you is the "On Error Resume Next" at the top of your code. Use this only when you have a specific purpose, not to bypass all errors. It should be quickly followed by "On Error GoTo 0". Especially during debugging you need to see the errors.

Comment: I tried that now and it gave me an error but it was on a totally different thing. since i was trying edit the entire msg to add the name of the file being removed. once i removed that the same issue kept happening. @niton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete an attachment, call Attachment.Delete. You might want to use `for i = Attachments.Count to 1 step -1` loop instead of "for each" since deleting an attachment will change the collection count. You might also want to check the attachment extension/etc. first to make sure you are not removing embedded HTML image attachment.

To insert attachment as a reference, call Attachments.Add specifying the new attachment location, but pass olByReference as the second parameter.

Comment: I tried doing that but it isn't deleting my attachments now. @Dimitry Streblechenko

Comment: What happens? You get an error? objAttachments.Count
 is still the same? Or something else?

Comment: my code above remains the same just in the for each i put `for i = Item.Attachments.Count to 1 step -1` and at the bottom `next i` @Dimitry Streblenchenko i also don;t get an error it just doesn't remove it

Comment: Did you try to step through your code in the debugger and check if Attachments.Count is decremented after calling Attachment.Delete? I'd also avoud using multiple dot notation - retrieve the attachment object at the beginning of the loop instead of getting a new object over and over again by calling objAttachments.Item(i)

Comment: i just tried it and it is just skipping the whole loop... i'm not sure if i've starting the attachment count in the wrong place but it seems that it isn't counting the attachments. @Dmitry Streblechenko

Comment: Which loop (you have 2)? Which condition is not satisfied causing the loop to bail out?

Comment: the inner for loop to get each attachment. I've created a lngCount variable and i've assigned it the value of 'attach.count' but when i step through the code the attachment count is not satisfied. @Dmitry Streblechenko

Comment: this is the current loop i have to retrieve attachments and deleting them. it is working bu my new issue is that when there is multiple attachments it only deletes one. Can you please help me modify it to work? @Dmitry Streblechenko  `For Each Attach In Item.Attachments
        
            If Searchdate < SentDate Then
                FileName = saveFolder & "\" & Attach.FileName
                Attach.SaveAsFile FileName
                Strfile = Attach.FileName & ";" & Strfile
                i = i + 1
            End If
            Attach.Delete   
        Next Attach`

Comment: Seems you did not understand the comments in the almost working code in my answer "We need to use a count down loop for removing items from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets confused and only every other item is removed."

Comment: Are you sure Item.Attachments.Count is greater than zero?

Comment: That's the problem with it, when i run it i'm testing it just on emails that have attachments and when i step through the code Item.Attachments.count remains equal to 0 for some reason and i'm initializing it inside of the for loop and i even tried it outside of it. @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: Are you sure you have the right emails selected? Does objMsg.Subject show the right subject?

Comment: i don't have the objMsg.Subject defined on my code. you might be looking at the code provided by the other guy @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: I know you don't - I was suggesting displaying the message subject using MsgBox to make sure you are processing the right message.

Comment: did it, it is taking the correct email just the count is still remaining 0 even though there is an attachment in it @DmitryStreblechenko

Comment: What do you see in OutlookSpy if you select the problematic message, click Item on the OutlookSpy ribbon, expand Attachments property, select Count?

Comment: I got it i managed to do all of the things i needed i was just making a mistake when i was using the `for i` what i needed to do was `for i = attach.count to 1 to step -1` and then `next i` at the bottom. @DmitryStreblechenko Thank you so much for your help